# Add a whole list of integers to binary tree F#

Tags: f#, tree

I have this code

```
type Tree<'T when 'T: comparison> = 
| Empty 
| Node of 'T * Tree<'T> * Tree<'T>

let rec insert value = function
| Empty -> Node(value, Empty, Empty)
| Node(v, left, right) when value < v -> Node(v, insert value left, right)
| Node(v, left, right) when value > v -> Node(v, left, insert value right)
| Node(_, _, _) as n -> n
```

but insteed of adding one integer I want to add a whole list of integers. Example:

```
let tree = addList [5;2;1;6;7];;
```

and the list should be added to the tree

Answer (score 5):

You can simply do a fold like this

```
let tree = List.fold (fun tree x -> inser­t x tree)­ Empty­ [5;2;1;6;7];;
```

At each step you return a new tree, to which you add the next element during the next step. Instead of `Empty` you can use any existing tree to which you want to add the list of elements.

Comment: Nice, is there any way to do it without any inbuilt functions?

Comment: You could reinvent the wheel and write your own version of List.fold. Have a look [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lists#List.fold_and_List.foldBack)